# Getting Listbox Item Index from Button Click

Tags: wpf, listbox, itemtemplate

So I'm using a button in the `DataTemplate` of my `Listbox` `ItemTemplate`. Any ideas how I would grab the index of the item of the `Listbox` from the button click? I can't see to grab the button's parent.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Img}">
                <Button Click="lstButton_Click">...
```

Comment: Is the Item selected when you click the button?

Comment: Nope the selected index changed event doesn't trigger.

Comment: You could use an ICommand instead of ClickEvent, then you could pass the actual Item as the CommandParameter, or set the Buttons Tag property to the Item and access the Button Tag property from the event handler

Answer (score 12):

```
     private void lstButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
                Button button = sender as Button;           
                int index = _myListBoxName.Items.IndexOf(button.DataContext);
//or try this
                index = _myListBoxName.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(button.DataContext);
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `Index` property in your view model and set it when you add the view model object into your collection. And then you can access it in your event handler.

```
private void lstButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Img t = (sender as Button).DataContext as Img
        //Access t.Index here
    }
```