# ListBoxItem set EventSetter in Style

Tags: wpf, events

I'm trying to implement drag&drop. So I need to start the dragging operation in an eventhandler.
How do I have to set the eventhandler in a style correctly?

Have a look at my code

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"              
             mc:Ignorable="d">
        
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name">

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">

                    <EventSetter Event="MouseDown"                       Handler="OnMouseDownStartDrag" />

                </Style>
                
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

        </ListBox>
           
</UserControl>
```

I've tried to call *OnMouseDownStartDrag* in code behind, in the viewmodel of the usercontrol, where *MyItems* exists and in the single element of MyItems (some data class).

Unfortunately, *OnMouseDownStartDrag* is never called. What am I missing? Is something wrong with the style? Where should I place *OnMouseDownStartDrag* and in which way should it be called?

I using WPF 4.6.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the problem is not in how you set or where you set the EventHandler according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271375/how-to-capture-a-mouse-click-on-an-item-in-a-listbox-in-wpf).

You should try the **PreviewMouseDown** instead of **MouseDown**. So, it will be like

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyProject.UserControl1"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"              
         mc:Ignorable="d">
    
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}"  DisplayMemberPath="Name">

        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            
            <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ListBoxItem}}">

                <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseDown"                       Handler="OnMouseDownStartDrag" />

            </Style>
            
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    </ListBox>
```

I have tried that code with setting it from the style and it works.

Comment: With PreviewMouseDown it works fine, as long as one uses code behind. A Markupextension still ends up in an exception, but that is no problem, I'll get along. Thank you very much for your help, it is appreciated.